# Load dynamic video source from javascript?

Tags: javascript, video, random, setattribute

What I want to achieve is for the video source to be set randomly from "1.mp4" to "4.mp4", where the rand. int is generated on every load/refresh.

Javascript:

```
function getRndInteger(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) ) + min;
      }
      var video = document.getElementById("video");
      video.setAttribute('src', getRndInteger(1,4) + '.mp4');
      video.load();
```

HTML:

```
<video autoplay muted loop id="video"></video>
```

Unfortunately, no video plays when loading the website. I tried changing the src of a source as well, but it doesn't work using this method. I also tried adding video.play(); which doesn't work as well. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hi, Flerovium, your code looks good. May be you are loading the script before the html. try to keep the script in the footer.

Comment: Are the videos in the right directory ? what does your console say when you run what you have currently ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what i did wrong. The code works, but i used the attribute `type="javascript"` instead of `type="text/javascript"`. I'll keep the question up in case someone want to do something similar in js :)

I'd also like to thank you all for the help!

Comment: Hello Flerovium, You may accept your own answer so it will not show up as unanswered. This helps people see on first glance if the question has been solved.

Answer (score -1):

This script works fine in chrome.
Are you sure you run your JS script AFTER HTML is rendered?
Put your '' tag just before '' (body closing tag).
Are you sure you've got a valid MP4 files in given directory?

Do you get any errors?

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<video autoplay muted loop id="video"></video>

<script>

function getRndInteger(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) ) + min;
      }
var video = document.getElementById("video");
video.setAttribute('src', getRndInteger(1,4) + '.mp4');
video.load();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Answers are not meant to ask questions. Please use the comments system. For more information read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer